# Android Canvas Path#cubicTo. Как найти кординату точки на кривой линии?

Tags: android, svg, математика, canvas, кривые-безье

Использую метод Path#cubicTo для рисования кривой линии.

Например

```
cubicTo(
    x1 = 0, y1 = 100, 
    x2 = 0, y2 = 100,
    x3 = 50, y3 = 50)
```

В итоге прямую изгибает в нижнюю правую сторону, где я указал x2y2.

Далее передо мной стоит задача: поставить на длине от точки x1y1 до x3y3 точку на расстоянии 65% от первой точки.

Проблема в том, что прямая кривая и место для точки на линии найти надо используя какую-то формулу. И я не могу найти какую (

P.s. x2y2 это не точка а координата относительно, которых метод считает угол и Радиус для закругления. Насколько я понял, когда x2y2 равны точке x1y1 это значит, что закругление максимальное

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это мало относится конкретно к Android.

Кубическая кривая Безье задается двумя опорными и двумя контрольными точками.

Первая опорная точка - эта та точка в которую мы пришли последней командой пути.

Остальные 2 контрольные и вторая опорная - ваши три точки в аргументах команды `cubicTo`

Значения можно получить либо [по формуле](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5):

[image: формула]

либо итеративно, через производные точки (как подсказал господин MBo - это алгоритм [de Casteljau](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B6%D0%BE))

Производные точки находятся следующим образом:

На первой итерации берем входные 4 точки попарно `[0,1]` `[1,2]` `[2,3]` - на первой итерации 3 пары, находим линейной интерполяцией между ними 3 точки (синие) в по времени, где `t=0` это первая точка а `t=1` вторая.

На второй итерации берем попарно точки получившиеся на предыдущей итерации и линейной интерполяцией получаем 2 зеленые точки.

На третьей итерации из 2х точек со второй итерации получаем точку на кривой

Все это дело дает точки, соединив которые Вы увидите следующую картину, по-моему не плохо показывающую геометрический способ нахождения точки на кривой Безье:

[image: пример]

Вот сниппет на `svg` из которого получено изображение выше:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=600 height=200>
  <path id="result" stroke="red"></path>
  <text x=10 y=170></text>
  <circle id="pt" r=10 stroke="red" stroke-width='3' fill="none"></circle>
</svg>
<div class="ui">
t:<input type="range" onmousemove="upd()">
curve:<input id="curve" type="checkbox" onchange="d3.select('#result').attr('stroke', this.checked?'red':'transparent')" checked>
explain:<input id="explain" type="checkbox" onchange="upd()" checked>
</div>
<script>
let cubicBezier = [
  [50,50],    // начальная точка
  [120,120],  // первая контрольная точка
  [490,120],  // вторая контрольная точка
  [590,10]    // конечная точка
];

let lerp = (a, b, t) => a + (b-a)*t;
let lerp2 = (p1, p2, t) => [
  lerp(p1[0], p2[0], t), 
  lerp(p1[1], p2[1], t)
];

let step = (pts, t, color) => {
  let pairs = [];
  for (var i=0;i<pts.length-1;i++)
    pairs.push([pts[i], pts[i+1]])
  pairs = pairs.map(p => lerp2(p[0], p[1], t));
  
  d3.select('path.edge'+pts.length)
    .remove();
  
  if (d3.select('#explain').node().checked) 
  d3.select('svg')
    .append('path')
    .attr('stroke', color)
    .attr('pointer-events', 'none')
    .classed('edge'+pts.length, true)
    .attr('d', `M${pts}`);
    
  d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('circle.point'+pts.length)
    .remove();
    
  if (d3.select('#explain').node().checked)  
  d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('circle.point'+pts.length)
    .data(pairs)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'none')
    .attr('fill', color)
    .classed('point'+pts.length, true)
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('cx', d => d[0])
    .attr('cy', d => d[1])
 
   d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('text.point'+pts.length)
    .remove();
    
  if (d3.select('#explain').node().checked)    
  d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('text.point'+pts.length)
    .data(pairs)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .style('font-size', 11)
    .html((d,i) => `&nbsp;&nbsp;p${4-pts.length}${i}`)
    
    .classed('point'+pts.length, true)
    .attr('x', d => d[0])
    .attr('y', d => d[1]);  
    
  return pairs;
}

let upd = () => {
    let a = cubicBezier.slice(0);
    let t = d3.select('input').node().value/100;
    
    let b = step(a, t, 'blue');
    let c = step(b, t, 'green');
    let d = step(c, t, 'magenta');
    d3.select('circle#pt')
    .attr('cx', d[0][0])
    .attr('cy', d[0][1])
    
    d3.select('#result').attr('d', `M${a.shift()}C${a}`);
    d3.select('text').html(`${cubicBezier[0]} Path#cubicTo(${a})`);
}

upd();

d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('circle.point')
  .data(cubicBezier)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .classed('point', true)
  .attr('cx', d => d[0])
  .attr('cy', d => d[1])
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('r', 7)
  .call(d3.drag().on('drag', function(d) {
    let m = d3.mouse(d3.select('svg').node())
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('cx', d[0] = m[0])
      .attr('cy', d[1] = m[1])
    upd();  
  }))
</script>
<style>
body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

path {
  fill:none;
}


#result {
  stroke-width:3;
}

text{
  font-family:arial;
  user-select:none;
}

.ui{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
</style>
```

PS. Как верно ответил господин MBo, простой формулы для нахождения длины кривой Безье нет, и для находжении точки на определенном расстоянии от начала необходимо как минимум построить полилинию с приемлимо минимальным шагом и посчитать значение через ее длину.

Answer (score 3):

Кубическая кривая задаётся четырьмя точками, начальная точка PO - текущая на момент вызова. Точки P1 и P2 - контрольные, кривая обычно через них не проходит.

Кривая параметрическая, определяется уравнением от t в пределах 0..1

```
P(t) = P0*(1-t)^3 + 3*P1*(1-t)^2*t + 3*P2*(1-t)*t^2 + P3*t^3
```

С использованием данной формулы или метода de Casteljau, описанного в ответе Stranger in the Q, легко рассчитать точку, находящуюся при параметре t=0.65.
Однако в общем случае **длина** данного куска **не будет** равной 0.65 от общей длины кривой.

К сожалению, простого метода (замкнутой формулы) нахождения длины кривой Безье нет, т.к. эта длина выражается через эллиптические интегралы.

Можно посчитать аппроксимацию полилинией, как, например, [здесь](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/cbezarclen.html), или [здесь](https://www.lemoda.net/maths/bezier-length/index.html), или использовать гауссовы квадратуры для численной аппроксимации интеграла (если нужна точность).