# Как реализовать кривую Безье(B-Splines) с возможностью редактирования опорных точек?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

**Кортеж - это точки, которые нужно редактировать.**

```
import sys
import itertools

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize

trajectories = [
    [(50, 50), (280, 175), (150, 240)],
    #[(80, 80), (210, 225), (300, 300), (340, 40)],
]

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widthApp, self.heightApp  = 700, 550
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.setGeometry(680, 400, self.widthApp, self.heightApp)
        self.setWindowTitle('Traj')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawLine(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawLine(self, qp):
        path = QPainterPath()
        delta_x, delta_y = None, None

        for trajectory in trajectories:
            for x, y in trajectory:
                if (delta_x is not None) and (delta_y is not None):
                    delta_x = min(x, delta_x)
                    delta_y = min(y, delta_y)
                else:
                    delta_x, delta_y = x, y

        def draw_trajectory(trajectory):

            self.k_width = 1
            self.k_height = 1

            first_point_x, first_point_y = trajectory[0]
            first_point_y = -first_point_y + self.height()

            path.moveTo(first_point_x * self.k_width - delta_x, first_point_y * self.k_height + delta_y)

            for x, y in trajectory[1:]:
                y = -y + self.height()
                path.lineTo(x * self.k_width - delta_x, y * self.k_height + delta_y)

        for trajectory in trajectories:
            draw_trajectory(trajectory)
            qp.drawPath(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Пример готового сплайна**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/978755/188366

Comment: итеративный метод поддерживает любое кол-во контрольных точек

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/EzVrxO

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю правильно ли я вас понял, но это надо попробовать:

```
import sys
import itertools

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


trajectories = [
    [(50, 50), (280, 175), (150, 240)],
    [(80, 80), (210, 225), (300, 300), (340, 40)],
]


class Widget(QWidget):                                            # +++
    def __init__(self, myList):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMaximumWidth(170)

        self.spinBox1 = QSpinBox(value=myList[0]) 
        self.spinBox1.setRange(0, 900)
        self.spinBox1.setValue(myList[0])
        self.spinBox1.setPrefix(" xPosStart:   ")
        self.spinBox2 = QSpinBox(value=myList[1]) 
        self.spinBox2.setRange(0, 900)
        self.spinBox2.setValue(myList[1])
        self.spinBox2.setPrefix(" yPosStart:   ")
        self.spinBox3 = QSpinBox(value=myList[2]) 
        self.spinBox3.setRange(0, 900)
        self.spinBox3.setValue(myList[2])
        self.spinBox3.setPrefix(" controlPoint1:   ")
        self.spinBox4 = QSpinBox(value=myList[3]) 
        self.spinBox4.setRange(0, 900)
        self.spinBox4.setValue(myList[3])
        self.spinBox4.setPrefix(" controlPoint2:   ")
        self.spinBox5 = QSpinBox(value=myList[4]) 
        self.spinBox5.setRange(0, 900)
        self.spinBox5.setValue(myList[4])
        self.spinBox5.setPrefix(" controlPoint3:   ")
        self.spinBox6 = QSpinBox(value=myList[5]) 
        self.spinBox6.setRange(0, 900)
        self.spinBox6.setValue(myList[5])
        self.spinBox6.setPrefix(" controlPoint4:   ")
        self.spinBox7 = QSpinBox(value=myList[6]) 
        self.spinBox7.setRange(0, 900)
        self.spinBox7.setValue(myList[6])
        self.spinBox7.setPrefix(" xPosEnd:   ")
        self.spinBox8 = QSpinBox(value=myList[7]) 
        self.spinBox8.setRange(0, 900)
        self.spinBox8.setValue(myList[7])
        self.spinBox8.setPrefix(" yPosEnd:   ")        

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox4)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox5)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox6)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox7)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinBox8)


class PaintWidget(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, x, y, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, parent=None):
        super(PaintWidget, self).__init__(parent)    
        self.widthApp, self.heightApp  = 700, 550
        self.setGeometry(580, 120, self.widthApp, self.heightApp)

        self.xPosStart = x
        self.yPosStart = y
        self.controlPoint1 = c1
        self.controlPoint2 = c2
        self.controlPoint3 = c3
        self.controlPoint4 = c4
        self.xPosEnd = c5
        self.yPosEnd = c6

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawLine(qp)

        self.bezierCurve(qp)                                         # <<< +++

        qp.end()


    def bezierCurve(self, qp):                                       # <<< +++
        ''' Это добавляет кубическую кривую Безье между startPoint и endPoint 
        используя контрольные точки, указанные controlPoint1, и controlPoint2. '''
        qp.setPen(QPen(QColor("red")))

        """ или так:
        startPoint    = QPointF(0, 0)         
        controlPoint1 = QPointF(100, 300)     
        controlPoint2 = QPointF(200, 100)     
        endPoint      = QPointF(300, 300)     
        cubicPath = QPainterPath(startPoint)
        cubicPath.cubicTo(controlPoint1, controlPoint2, endPoint)  
        """
        # или так: 
        cubicPath = QPainterPath(QPointF(self.xPosStart, self.yPosStart))        
        cubicPath.cubicTo(self.controlPoint1, self.controlPoint2, self.controlPoint3, 
                          self.controlPoint4, self.xPosEnd, self.yPosEnd)         
        qp.drawPath(cubicPath);


    def drawLine(self, qp):
        path = QPainterPath()
        delta_x, delta_y = None, None

        for trajectory in trajectories:
            for x, y in trajectory:
                if (delta_x is not None) and (delta_y is not None):
                    delta_x = min(x, delta_x)
                    delta_y = min(y, delta_y)
                else:
                    delta_x, delta_y = x, y

        def draw_trajectory(trajectory):
            self.k_width  = 1
            self.k_height = 1
            first_point_x, first_point_y = trajectory[0]
            first_point_y = -first_point_y + self.height()
            path.moveTo(first_point_x * self.k_width - delta_x, first_point_y * self.k_height + delta_y)
            for x, y in trajectory[1:]:
                y = -y + self.height()
                path.lineTo(x * self.k_width - delta_x, y * self.k_height + delta_y)
        for trajectory in trajectories:
            draw_trajectory(trajectory)
            qp.drawPath(path)         


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        myList = [0, 0, 100, 200, 600, 800, 500, 100]                      # +++

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.widget = Widget(myList)
        self.widget.spinBox1.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)
        self.widget.spinBox2.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)
        self.widget.spinBox3.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)
        self.widget.spinBox4.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)
        self.widget.spinBox5.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)
        self.widget.spinBox6.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)
        self.widget.spinBox7.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)
        self.widget.spinBox8.valueChanged.connect(self.spinBoxChanged)

        self.paintWidget = PaintWidget(self.widget.spinBox1.value(), 
                                       self.widget.spinBox2.value(),
                                       self.widget.spinBox3.value(),
                                       self.widget.spinBox4.value(),
                                       self.widget.spinBox5.value(),
                                       self.widget.spinBox6.value(),
                                       self.widget.spinBox7.value(),
                                       self.widget.spinBox8.value(),
                                      )  

        self.grid = QHBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.paintWidget)        

    def spinBoxChanged(self, v):
        if self.sender().prefix() == " xPosStart:   ":       self.paintWidget.xPosStart = v
        elif self.sender().prefix() == " yPosStart:   ":     self.paintWidget.yPosStart = v
        elif self.sender().prefix() == " controlPoint1:   ": self.paintWidget.controlPoint1 = v
        elif self.sender().prefix() == " controlPoint2:   ": self.paintWidget.controlPoint2 = v
        elif self.sender().prefix() == " controlPoint3:   ": self.paintWidget.controlPoint3 = v
        elif self.sender().prefix() == " controlPoint4:   ": self.paintWidget.controlPoint4 = v
        elif self.sender().prefix() == " xPosEnd:   ":       self.paintWidget.xPosEnd = v
        elif self.sender().prefix() == " yPosEnd:   ":       self.paintWidget.yPosEnd = v

        self.paintWidget.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
    ex.setGeometry(580, 120, 700, 500)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Traj')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Иван  так правильно ли я вас понял ?