# Как реализовать анимацию движений волн в Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-customview

Нужно реализовать эффект движения нескольких волн. Знаю что нужно копать в сторону canvas и кривой безье, но не получается подступиться к задаче. Есть ли похожие примеры или материал на эту тему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уже умеете рисовать на канве не кривую Безье а например простую линию?

Comment: Сделать статическую линию с этим нет проблем

Comment: а менять точки со временем?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978700