# сложная фигура canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как нарисовать эту фигуру в canvas с помощью javascript?
Вот сама фигура: [image]

Comment: Как вариант - сделайте сначала SVG-кривую с этой фигурой, и потом нарисуйте её методом Path2D - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458239/draw-path-in-canvas-with-svg-path-data-svg-paths-to-canvas-paths

Comment: Используйте кривые Безье, загуглите `js canvas bezier`

Comment: с ней надо потом что-то делать? если нет то картинку поверх холста и нарисуйте, если да - то Вам уже предложили 2 варианта.

Comment: Как я понял, сначала нужно сделать из этого svg, потом просто скормить в Path2D, далее сделать fill и stroke, верно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот, как-то так, контрольные точки подбирал на глаз.

Черная линия соединяет контрольные и опорные точки двух кривых Безье, которые образуют фигуру

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = 'wheat';

ctx.fill(new Path2D(`
  M40 300 
  C 1 270 1 210 50 150
  C 180 0 250 1 300 50
  v300
`));

ctx.stroke(new Path2D(`
   M40 300 
   1 270 1 210 50 150
   180 1 250 1 300 50
`));
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=300 height=300 />
```

Comment: Допустим с кривыми безье я разобрался, если я хочу нарисовать сам, как мне расположить опорные точки так, чтобы всё совпадало пиксель в пиксель. Если я буду рисовать на глаз, думаю получится не совсем то.

Comment: Вариантов много, можно усложнить код и двигать точки мышкой, можно взять path в каком нибудь векторном редакторе

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/978755/188366